# Spring Data JPA repository error: Could not resolve matching constructor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are getting this error upon start of our web app.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'insurancePolicyRepo': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

The InsurancePolicyRepo class:

```
interface InsurancePolicyRepo extends JpaRepository<InsurancePolicy, String> {
    InsurancePolicy findOneByCurrentIdValue(String currentIdValue)
}
```

The Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_policy")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class InsurancePolicy {

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_type")
    String idType

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_value")
    String idValue

    ....other fields...
```

The database config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 'com.xyzinsurance.policy', transactionManagerRef = 'defaultTransactionManager')
class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject())
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        def entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource)
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan('com.xyzinsurance.policy')
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName('defaultPersistenceUnit')
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter())
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap([
                'eclipselink.weaving'             : 'false',
                'eclipselink.logging.level'       : 'INFO',
                'eclipselink.logging.level.sql'   : 'INFO',
                'eclipselink.cache.shared.default': 'false'])
        return entityManagerFactoryBean
    }

    @Bean
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        // TODO configure based on db.driverClassName
        def jpaVendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter()
        jpaVendorAdapter.databasePlatform = 'org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform'
        jpaVendorAdapter.showSql = true
        return jpaVendorAdapter
    }
}
```

What we tried to do to fix the error: (but didnt work)

1. Added @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor to the InsurancePolicy entity class
2. Added @Repository to the InsurancePolicyRepo class

We are using the following versions of spring and jpa

```
a. spring boot 1.3.4
b. spring-boot-started-data-jpa:1.5.11.RELEASE
c. spring-data-commons:1.13.11
```

Anyone can help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error may raised because while creating the entity in the springboot one column must be of Primary Key. Make one column of the entity as primary key by using the @Id annotation.

Thanks.

Comment: There's already an @Id field in the entity. I just forgot to include it in my post